# Oracle SQL: invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Could anyone explain to me why dLoad is an invalid identifier in the GROUP BY line?
This runs fine on Mysql but I can't get it to work with Oracle.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DoctorsLoad AS
    SELECT dID, gender, specialty, 'Overloaded' AS dLoad
    FROM Doctor D, Examine E
    WHERE D.dID = E.doctor_id
    GROUP BY dID, gender, specialty, dLoad
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
    UNION
    SELECT dID, gender, specialty, 'Underloaded' AS dLoad
    FROM Doctor D, Examine E
    WHERE D.dID = E.doctor_id
    GROUP BY dID, gender, specialty, dLoad
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10;
```

Comment: What is Overloaded? If its a column name why is it quotes and then dLoad is a column alias which cannot be used in group by clause

Comment: It is a constant string that will be placed in the column dLoad.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should prefix the columns with the approriate table alias. Makes a more "stable" SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Oracle RDMS, you cannot use an alias in the `GROUP BY` clause, but for a literal like 'Overloaded' you do not need to include it in the group by anyway.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DoctorsLoad AS
    SELECT dID, gender, specialty, 'Overloaded' AS dLoad
    FROM Doctor D, Examine E
    WHERE D.dID = E.doctor_id
    GROUP BY dID, gender, specialty
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dID, gender, specialty, 'Underloaded' AS dLoad
    FROM Doctor D, Examine E
    WHERE D.dID = E.doctor_id
    GROUP BY dID, gender, specialty
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10;
```

I also suggest using a `UNION ALL` which avoids a filter operation to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: Thanks, I could have sworn I tried removing it from GROUP BY but maybe I was mistaken. This worked.